# npm install locally

Tags: node.js, npm

In the past when I installed packages using npm(>=1.0) they would be installed locally, but not  anymore.

### My setup:

- First I use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install node.js.
- My operating System:

  ```
  alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/so/6513101$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
  DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu<br>
  DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
  DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
  DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
  ```
- My node version:

  ```
  alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/so/6513101$ node -v
  v0.4.8
  ```
- My npm version:

  ```
  alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/so/6513101$ npm -v
  1.0.15
  ```

### Installing random package

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/so/6513101$ npm install notifo
notifo@0.0.2 ../../../node_modules/notifo
```

In the past it would install into the same directory but it does not install in the same directory anymore. is my npm/node.js broken or am I missing something or does npm not anymore install local packages(inside same folder => `~/node/so/6513101/node_modules`)  which I thought was a cool feature because I could `bundle` all my dependencies so that other users did not have to install npm to use my code(I still believe users should install npm because it is a great product). The `bundle` command is gone so I can't use that? Could someone please explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

npm walks up the folder tree until it finds a `node_modules` or a `package.json` and uses that as the root.  What does `npm root` print out?

If you `mkdir node_modules` or create a package.json file, then it'll use the cwd.

EDIT: I won't see updates you post here.  For better results, just post everything in the github issue, and let's do the support over there.

Comment: hi Isaacs, thanks for the fast response. You are really amazing and I really like npm. I uploaded the commands I performed to http://pastebin.com/rctLbi3i. Most of the times I zip the folder upload to github and boom(all dependencies). But npm root now points to `/home/alfred/node_modules` instead of cwd. Is that something new? But you are right that when I create `node_modules` in cwd than after installing package it can be found in `node_modules` dir. Thanks for the help, but I am still a little confused. Did you update npm in anyway that I have different behaviour. I hope I made any sense.

Comment: @isaacs Is this also true when installing npm itself locally? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560416/how-can-my-module-require-a-specific-version-of-npm