# How can I deploy node modules in a Meteor app on meteor.com?

Tags: meteor

I have an application that uses the node twit module that is available via

```
npm install twit
```

I deployed the node module locally from
    .meteor/local/build/server/

So, it is visible at 
    .meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/twit

I tried installing it at project root but the project did not find the module.  Which led me to the above solution which works.

My application now runs fine locally.  I am able to run and do everything and can interact with Twitter from my Meteor server side or client side depending on what I want to do.  No crashes.

When I deploy to meteor.com through the command

```
meteor deploy [appname] --password
```

The application deploys successfully.

When I attempt to access the (app at anonistream.meteor.com)[anonistream.meteor.com] from a browser it fails and the logs contain this error.

```
[Mon May 07 2012 01:59:53 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING
node.js:201
   throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
         ^
Error: Cannot find module 'twit'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (module.js:370:17)
at app/server/server.js:2:12
at /meteor/containers/84162a7c-24e8-bf26-6fd8-e4ec13b2a935/bundle/server/server.js:111:21
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function.<anonymous>
 (/meteor/containers/84162a7c-24e8-bf26-6fd8-     e4ec13b2a935/bundle/server/underscore.js:76:11)
at /meteor/containers/84162a7c-24e8-bf26-6fd8-e4ec13b2a935/bundle/server/server.js:97:7
[Mon May 07 2012 01:59:53 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
[Mon May 07 2012 01:59:53 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 1
[Mon May 07 2012 02:29:55 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 24.94.158.145
[Mon May 07 2012 02:29:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 24.94.158.145
[Mon May 07 2012 02:30:46 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 24.94.158.145
[Mon May 07 2012 02:30:50 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 24.94.158.145
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this might be accomplished?

Comment: Just checking...but is twit included in your `package.json` file?

Comment: I wasn't aware I had to build a meteor package to include twit in my deploy.  I will have to look into that to see if that is the case.  I assumed that anything in the node_modules directly was pushed on a deploy.  I am going to dig through the source tomorrow to see what I can find!  Unless someone else posts the answer that is!

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure either...looking forward to hearing what others have to say.

Comment: Personally, I have a package.json for all my meteor projects now. However I only deploy to Heroku now (for advanced apps with node dependencies). Here's how: https://github.com/matb33/heroku-meteor-npm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally, I wrote like this.
it works both in local and meteor sever. thx Ian :D

install npm module inside "app/public":

```
    app/public# npm install MODULE_NAME
```

inside app/server/server.js:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
    var path = require('path');
    var base = path.resolve('.');
    var isBundle = path.existsSync(base + '/bundle');
    var modulePath = base + (isBundle ? '/bundle/static' : '/public') + '/node_modules';

    var MODULE_NAME = require(modulePath + '/MODULE_NAME');
});
```

Comment: Spectrum, are you able to provide any kind of example? I can't make it work.
Everytime I make changes to the app folder it gets overwritten when meteor is restarting.

Comment: Alright, I got it working.
Had to add this line:
`var fs = require('fs');` and modify:
`var isBundle = path.existsSync(base + '/bundle');` into
`var isBundle = fs.existsSync(base + '/bundle');`

Comment: Note: since Meteor 0.6.0, `__meteor_bootstrap__.require` has been obsoleted by [Npm.require()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351543/1269037)

Comment: If you want to use external npm packages. Use Npm smart package(https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm).
It works like a charm :)

Comment: This is the 2 year old way to do it. Please see the other answers.

Answer (score 14):

As of Meteor 6.0, now we need to use Npm.require() instead. Additionally, we need to declare the module as global variables, since Meteor now has file-level scope.

```
  var path = Npm.require('path');
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var base = path.resolve('.');
  var isBundle = fs.existsSync(base + '/bundle');
  var modulePath = base + (isBundle ? '/bundle/static' : '/public') + '/node_modules';
  MODULE_NAME = Npm.require(modulePath + '/MODULE_NAME'); // NOTE, this is going to be a global variable
```

Comment: Can you clarify where to put the Npm.require() statement within a meteor project?

Comment: So when using npm packages in Meteor, you have to do it this way, instead of just using Meteor.require? If the npm module is in the public/node_modules folder, is the npm module available on both the client and server? Does this method of using npm modules lead to problems down the road? I am just confused as to what the best way to integrate npm modules into my project to use on the server.

Comment: @supertrue: My comment is a bit late, but this is a sort of reply to the answer by spectrum (the accepted answer currently). So it can be in app/server/server.js.

Answer (score 7):

Answer found from JonathanKingston on meteor irc.  Referred to [meteoric project](https://github.com/me/meteorirc)

Put node modules in the projects public directory.

Use code like this to make sure it loads.

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
var path = require("path");
var fs = require('fs');
var Twit;
var twitPath = 'node_modules/twit';

var base = path.resolve('.');
if (base == '/'){
  base = path.dirname(global.require.main.filename);   
}

var publicPath = path.resolve(base+'/public/'+twitPath);
var staticPath = path.resolve(base+'/static/'+twitPath);

if (path.existsSync(publicPath)){
  Twit = require(publicPath);
}
else if (path.existsSync(staticPath)){
  Twit = require(staticPath);
}
else{
  console.log('node_modules not found');
}
```

meteor deploy should work find after that, sill me for putting my node modules in the server dirs

Comment: You left out the line of code which allows you to `require` on Meteor: `var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;`. This tripped me up for a bit, and I know a lot of people get pointed here from IRC.

Comment: path.existsSync() is now fs.existsSync()

Comment: Note: since Meteor 0.6.0, `__meteor_bootstrap__.require` has been obsoleted by [Npm.require()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351543/1269037)

Answer (score 4):

Just spent a half hour figuring out the "install npm module inside `app/public` step and thought I'd save the next person some time.  From your app's home directory:

```
cd public
mkdir node_modules
npm install foo
```

By default, `npm install foo` installs "locally," but if there's no `node_modules` folder in your current directory then it moves up the directory tree looking for one.  I was ending up with the package installing in `$HOME/node_modules/foo` instead of the local project.  Fine for `localhost`, but not so much for deployment.

(Thanks to [npm install locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514621/npm-install-locally) for solving my root problem.)

Comment: Followup: A while later I found the meteorite package `npm` to do this type of thing, and it works like a charm.  If you ended up here, you may want to check out the [Meteor Hacks](http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html) article on it.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me with meteor 0.8.x and node_modules being installed in ./public of my app:

```
var path = Npm.require('path')
var fs = Npm.require('fs')
var base = path.resolve('.')
var isBundle = fs.existsSync(base + '/bundle')
var modulePath = base + (isBundle ? '/bundle/static' : '/../client/app') + '/node_modules/'

var twit  = Npm.require(modulePath+'rssparser')
```

It may also be a good idea to create packages.json file within ./public for easier updates/installs through npm.

Long live Meteor!

Comment: When running on my local I can just npm install in the root folder for my app and then use Meteor.require('package') But when uploading to Meteor.com testing servers I had to do it this way. Is this the same as using Meteor.require()? Have you run into any downsides?

Answer (score 1):

Changed:

```
var modulePath = base + (isBundle ? '/bundle/static' : '/../client/app') + '/node_modules/'
```

to:

```
var modulePath = base + (isBundle ? '/bundle/static' : '/../web.browser/app') + '/node_modules/'
```

Comment: INSANE! You hit at the right time exactly when I needed that

Answer (score 0):

You

```
base = base + "/bundle"
```

to get this to work.