# How to use node.js libraries that have transitive dependencies with Meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor

It is possible to use node.js packages within Meteor as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691513/it-possible-use-a-nodejs-package-inside-meteor-app), however as `require` is not defined globally, packages having transitive dependencies (as for example xml2js or aws-lib) break with

`ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Any ideas on how to fix or work around this issue without altering the libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed the instructions from your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691513/it-possible-use-a-nodejs-package-inside-meteor-app). I used the node-xml2js library to test this with the [test fixture from the code base](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/blob/master/test/fixtures/sample.xml) and achieved it in the following way.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

    // This solves the issue
    var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;

    // The example from node-xml2js readme
    var fs = require('fs'),
        xml2js = require('xml2js');

    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    fs.readFile('/home/prashant/order.xml', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log('Done');
        });
    });
});
```

I think the key was to define a variable `require` and assign it to Meteor's require function. When Meteor loads the server assets, it also loads `require` and solves the problem of the transitive dependency. I made no changes to the node-xml2js library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587964/where-do-we-put-node-modules-we-install-by-npm-in-a-meteor-project

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of Meteor (0.6.3, and presumably onwards), you need to use `Npm.require()` instead of `require()` by itself.