# Jade-Handlebars package preventing Meteor server from starting

Tags: meteor, pug, meteorite

I was attempting to use the jade-handlebars (https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/meteor-jade-handlebars) package from atmosphere. I installed it successfully using meteorite. The problem is when I attempt to run my meteor server I get the following error message/output on startup:

> Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment. No dependency
>
> info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
>
> => Errors prevented startup: Exception while bundling application:
>
> ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at /home/ewillis1/collaboratum/packages/jade-handlebars/package.js:5:21

The specific line it is referencing is this in package.js

> var fs            = require('fs');

Any help or direction would be appreciated if you can help me to get this package working with Meteor 0.6.4!

Comment: Try using Npm.require instead of require alone.

Comment: @saimeunt that's the conclusion I came to as well. However after converting all require() to Npm.require(), I am now getting errors due to, "too many sumbolic links encountered"

No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: ELOOP, too many symbolic links encountered

Comment: The problem was from when I accidentally used mrt to add a package while sitting in my jade-handlebars folder.

Comment: Do you have any plans on forking and updating the package? :) If not I think I'll give it a go this weekend.

Comment: @Magnus I was just looking at it, and a bunch of the changes I've been making on my own are in pull requests ><

I wont be doing it this weekend, but I might give it a solid go next week haha. If you do get started link me to your repo and I'll help as well.

Comment: JH is a cool idea but may be abandonware. I'd be psyched to see a maintained version. If for some reason it doesn't work out, you are welcome to try [my way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104887/jade-templating-in-meteor/14541874#14541874) of using jade with meteor (if you are using CS).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007054/1408362

I found a partial answer to my own question. Seeing as the jade-handlebars package was last updated 7 months ago(at this time), it was using the basic "require()" method in its package.js file, when newer versions of meteor(0.6.4 at this time) want you to use Npm.require() see the relevant stackoverflow post I am linking.

Now the issue that I encounter is this

```
No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: ELOOP, too many symbolic links encountered '/home/ewillis1/myproject/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebar
s/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/
packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/pa
ckages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/pack
ages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packag
es/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages/jade-handlebars/packages
/jade-handlebars/jade/lib/index.js'
```

The second issue was due to an error I made when I accidentally used mrt to install jade-handlebars while in my jade-handlebars folder