# Should I install npm modules for Meteor in /usr/lib or /usr/local?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

In [Where do we put node modules we install by npm in a Meteor project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10683052/1913737), the accepted answer indicates that you should install with this command:

> cd /usr/local/meteor/lib/ && npm install

But process.env is telling me that $NODE_PATH is `/usr/lib/meteor/lib/`

Does this mean the correct place to install node modules (for local use, e.g. Chai) is now `/usr/lib/meteor/lib/` instead of `/usr/local/meteor/lib/`?

Most of the questions about this are dated April/May '12, while in mid-June '12 it appears that a change was made to the way NODE_PATH was set. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/b7632579296257c10bf640a5f00716c3d440de71

Comment: Have you just tried either of them? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

`.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules` is a **symbolic link** to the directory you need to install the module in.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated as of now since the symlink doesn't exist anymore.