# Scraping with Meteor.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, meteor, cheerio

Can I scrape with meteor.js? Just discovered `cheerio` which works excellent combined with `request`. Can I use these with meteor, or is there something similar?

Do you have an working example?

Comment: Similar, if not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034453/how-can-one-parse-html-server-side-with-meteor

Comment: This question inspired me to record a related screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA0_0SPd3P8 thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Of course! Its hard to imagine what meteor can't do! First you need something to handle the remote http requests. In your meteor directory in the terminal run `meteor add http` to add the `Meteor.http` package, also `npm install cheerio` (have a look at [another SO question on how to install npm modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587964/where-do-we-put-node-modules-we-install-by-npm-in-a-meteor-project) to see exactly where to install external npm modules.

Here is an example that might help you out a bit, it scrapes the [current time](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136).

Server js

```
require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require; //to use npm require must be exposed.
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

Meteor.methods({
    getTime: function () {
        result = Meteor.http.get("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136");
        $ = cheerio.load(result.content);
        CurrentTime = $('#ct').html();
        return CurrentTime;
    }
});
```

Client side script:

```
Meteor.call("getTime", function(error, result) {
    alert("The current time is " + result); 
});
```

I hope this is helpful. amongst with Cheerio there are also other node frameworks such as node.io

Comment: do you have any recommendations for simulating JS to scrape? Your example looks like it does only HTML

Comment: @FullStack If you need to do more advanced scraping take a look at using phantomjs.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is used in [this project](https://github.com/DeBraid/meteor-tutorial-http-and-session-vars) to scrape a tweetstorm:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.call('getTweets', function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    };

    Session.set("tweets", result);
  });

  Template.tweets.helpers({
    rant: function () {
      return Session.get("tweets");
    }
  });

}
```

**Server side**

```
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.startup(function () {
        var cheerio = Meteor.npmRequire('cheerio');

    Meteor.methods({
      getTweets: function () {
        result = Meteor.http.get("https://twitter.com/Royal_Arse/status/538330380273979393");
        $ = cheerio.load(result.content);
        var body = $('#stream-items-id > li:nth-child(n) > div > div > p').text();
        return body;
      },

    })

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to http://casperjs.org/ which is very useful. You can also do screenshots, automated test, etc...

Answer (score 0):

now you should use meteorhacks npm package https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm
and require this with :

```
var cheerio = Meteor.npmRequire('cherio');
```

worked for me :)