# How can one parse HTML server-side with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I want to be able to scrape links out of an HTML page that I am fetching with the Meteor.http method. Would be ideal to use jQuery on the server-side but I don't think this works.

Comment: I used npm and jQuery, for Meteor 1.0, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26721055/1197775

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider using [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) its just like jquery but more for scraping. I have tried to answer this before so I hope I do a better job this time.

its an npm module so first step install it (inside your project dir) with terminal:

```
meteor add http
cd .meteor
npm install cheerio
```

So now the code:

You need to use this in your server js/or equivalent

```
var cheerio = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('cheerio');
Meteor.methods({
last_action: function() {
       $ = cheerio.load(Meteor.http.get("https://github.com/meteor/meteor").content);
       return $('.commit-title').text().trim()      
    }
})
```

If you run this from your client side js, you will see the last action on meteors github branch:

```
Meteor.call("last_action",function(err,result){ console.log(result) } );
```

I got this as of today/feb 23rd

[image]

which the same as on github.com/meteor/meteor

[image]

Comment: I really love Meteor, it's just so much fun. Thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: With Meteor 1.2.1, `__meteor_bootstrap__.require('cheerio');` or `Meteor.require('cheerio');` doesnt work. Even some other posts suggest `Meteor.npmRequire('cheerio')` doesnt work. What worked for me is `Npm.required('cheerio')`, but still answer by @Akshat did help me scrap html response from `http` package.

Answer (score 10):

Use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), as Akshat suggests, but I would recommend a different way of using it, as of now, for Meteor 0.8.0.

First, install [npm for Meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/package/npm):

```
$ mrt add npm
```

Then modify `packages.json` to (of course you can have different version of cheerio, or other node packages as well):

```
{
  "cheerio": "0.15.0"
}
```

In `server.js` (or any other file, in server-side code) start:

```
var cheerio =  Meteor.require('cheerio');
```

The use cheerio in a way you like.

Upon running `$ meteor` it will automatically install cheerio.

Comment: thank you, this is the approach that finally worked!