# Require jQuery in Meteor server side

Tags: jquery, meteor, npm

I saw:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/ZlPPrH7SqrE

http://guaka.org/guaka-jquery-meteor-server-side-try-var-meteor-bootstrap-requirejquery-javascript-0

[Server-side jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255230/server-side-jquery)

[How can one parse HTML server-side with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034453/how-can-one-parse-html-server-side-with-meteor)

And I have not figured out a way to include jQuery in Meteor server side. Anyone knows?

I tried:

```
Npm.require('jquery')
Npm.require('jQuery')
```

But package is not found:

```
# Npm.require('jquery')
►[Error][Error: Cannot find module 'jquery']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this package https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

1. Run `$: meteor add meteorhacks:npm`
2. in `packages.json` specify npm package and it's version `{ "jquery": 2.1.1 }`
3. Require jQuery `Meteor.npmRequire("jquery");`
4. fire up your server `$: meteor`

Comment: in 1.0 there is another way, I will post it

Comment: Just a note, you can't do version strings like that. That's not valid JSON. Use
{
    "jquery": "2.1.1"
}
Instead

Answer (score 0):

**For Meteor 1.0**

Create `.meteor/package.json` with:

```
{
  "dependencies":{
    "jquery": "*"
  }
}
```

Then `cd .meteor` and run `npm install` to install jquery in `.meteor/node_modules`.

Then you can use in server `Npm.require('jquery')`.

And add `node_modules` in `.meteor/.gitignore` so you don't push dependencies that will be installed with `npm install`.

There is a problem though, npm does not keep track versions of installed packages. To do that, run `npm shrinkwrap` in `.meteor`, that way, when another developer run `npm install` in another machine will get the same version you installed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough just to specify the exact version of jQuery in `package.json`? I mean instead of running `npm shrinkwrap`