# Recommended way to use node.js modules with meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

Can someone please tell me what the recommended way to use a node.js package that one would install with npm locally (npm without -g option)?

One way someone recommended was:

```
    % cd myapp/.meteor/local/build/server/
    % npm install aws-lib
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-lib
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-lib
    npm ERR! Could not create /home/user/myapp/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/___aws-lib.npm
```

This fails because myapp/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules is symlinked to /usr/lib/meteor/lib/node_modules/.

I want to install it locally for a several reasons.  I want it to be portable as in, if I deploy the app somewhere else, I want all the dependencies to travel with it.  I don't want to do this as root.  It seems wrong to install stuff like this into /usr/lib/meteor.

Comment: The symlink was created with 'meteor create myapp', I didn't create it manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, `meteor bundle bundle.tar.gz` to get a `node`-deployable package of your app.
2. `tar -xvf bundle.tar.gz` and `cd bundle`.
3. In the bundle's `server` directory there is a `node_modules` directory.
4. `cd server & npm install aws-lib`

This is a deployment-ready package. Call `node bundle/main.js` to start it.

To actually use the module, you will have to call `__meteor_bootstrap__.require`.

Checkout this for a more detailed solution!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730509/1757994

Alternatively, you can wrap the `node` module as a package that includes the module's code and the `__meteor_bootstrap__.require` line. This is a good example of a simple shim:

https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js

And this is an example of a shim around a node module:

https://github.com/possibilities/meteor-awssum

I suspect this is the package you wanted in the first place...

Comment: The problem I see with this is that you disconnect the node_modules directory from meteor's installed node_modules directory.  When meteor is updated, the app won't get the updates without manual intervention.  This doesn't seem like a good long-term solution, perhaps it's the only solution?  Is there nothing like a search path for modules so that meteor's modules could be on the search path and then all combined into one directory when meteor bundle was run?

Comment: I would suggest making a Meteor package then that shims the node module you want to use.