# Using node-soap module with meteor app hosted on heroku

Tags: meteor

I know this is not hip at all, but I have to use SOAP in my Meteor project (I need only SOAP client functionality). Node-soap node.js module is great and it works on localhost using this hack: [How can I deploy node modules in a Meteor app on meteor.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476170/how-can-i-deploy-node-modules-in-a-meteor-app-on-meteor-com).

But when I deploy my app to Heroku I get then following:

```
2013-02-06T10:19:04+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:485
2013-02-06T10:19:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   process.dlopen(filename, module.exports);
2013-02-06T10:19:04+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2013-02-06T10:19:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/pu blic/node_modules/soap/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node: invalid ELF header
```

Which basically means that there is binary incompatibility of node_expat.node (the dependency of node-soap) precompiled for my Mac OS.

Any ideas how to install node-soap module properly? Tried to find something similar on atmospehre with no luck: all modules which has server part are very simple, without single 'require'.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install dependencies using package.json and NPM: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm