# Requiring npm in meteorite heroku buildpack

Tags: heroku, meteor, meteorite

Is there some way to modify this build pack

https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite

to install this npm

https://github.com/abh/node-stripe

it works fine on development but I cannot figure out how to install and require it on Heroku

I am requiring it using

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.require('stripe')(api_key)
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors like the one mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476170/how-can-i-deploy-node-modules-in-a-meteor-app-on-meteor-com)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a package.json in your meteor project with your npm dependencies (node-stripe for you).

Look at this project https://github.com/matb33/heroku-meteor-npm maybe it will help you..