# Meteor cannot find module "module"

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to install the [Spooky](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS) module in meteor (this one is in my public folder: app/public/node_modules).

I've read answers [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476170/how-can-i-deploy-node-modules-in-a-meteor-app-on-meteor-com) and added the following code in server/server.js

```
Meteor.startup ->
    path = Npm.require 'path'
    fs = Npm.require 'fs'
    base = path.resolve '.'
    isBundle = fs.existsSync base + '/bundle'
    modulePath = base + (if isBundle then '/bundle/static' else '/public') + '/node_modules'
    spooky = Npm.require modulePath + '/spooky'
```

But when I'm running meteor I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/mac/Documents/websites/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/public/node_modules/spooky'
```

Comment: just install the package with -g (`npm install -g packagename`). The `public` folder is outward facing and visible to everyone. You don't want that. Plus meteor/node doesn't it find it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a smart package to use Npm modules in your app. Alternatively you can use meteor-npm.

You can't use `Npm.require` on its own for non standard npm modules like spooky.

If you use meteor-npm you can install it with meteorite: `mrt add npm`

Then use `Meteor.require("spooky")` instead, after you have added the module to your packages.json. You can have a look here for more details: http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html.

The official way to do it is to make your own smart package to wrap the npm module in. There is an example of such a package: https://github.com/avital/meteor-xml2js-npm-demo

The example uses xml2js as the npm module, but you could swap the names around so its spooky instead.

Then you can add this package into your `/packages` folder (say with the name `spooky`), and add it to your meteor project with `meteor add spooky`.

The packages on atmosphere.meteor.com have more examples of this, they pretty much do the same thing (e.g stripe (https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/stripe)).

Comment: Thank you Akshat! :) By the way you wrote "the module to your package.json". It should be packages.json.

Answer (score 0):

[The article](https://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html) Akshat [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565769/819417) has been updated:

```sh
cd project
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

Edit `project/packages.json`:

```js
{
  "redis": "0.8.2",
  "github": "0.1.8"
}
```

Use those npm modules:

```js
var Github = Meteor.npmRequire('github');
var github = new Github();

github.gists.getFromUser({user: 'arunoda'}, function(err, gists) {
  console.log(gists);
});
```