# npm won't install packages locally. What's wrong?

Tags: node.js, installation, global, local, npm

I want to install packages locally, but npm is always installing packages to the global location. I'm running the following command:

```
npm install serialport
```

I do not have a .npmrc command and I'm not using the -g flag, so I don't know why it's not installing locally. Here's a snippet from the config dump showing that global is false:
    $ npm config ls -l | grep global
    global = false
    globalconfig = "/usr/local/etc/npmrc"
    globalignorefile = "/usr/local/etc/npmignore"

And the packages are still being installed like this

```
serialport@0.7.3 ../../../../node_modules/serialport
```

So unless I am totally wrong about what "local" means, this seems wrong. I was under the impression that "local" meant in the current working directory so that I could do a "require" in my main code file. See: http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/ as referenced in a previous npm related question.

Can someone please give me some hints on this? Thank you very much.

P.S. It's not specific to the serialport module. It's happening with all of them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Most of my answer can be found: http://npmjs.org/doc/folders.html#More-Information

What I understand is that npm will try to install it in a sensible location. So if you have a `project/node_modules` directory and you are in /project and do npm install it will use `product/node_modules`.

Now if you accidentally did a cd `project/css` and do npm install then npm will traverse up until it finds your `node_modules` directory. This is to prevent you from accidentally installing it in your `project/css`.

So in your case you have a node_module directory somewhere in the path of your project. So my guess is that you can fix it by either deleting that directory or manually creating a `node_modules` dir in your project folder.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that myself and tried to answer my own question, but new users can't do that until 8 hours later. Here's what I found that explained it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514621/npm-install-locally

Comment: No worries, I actually wasn't 100% sure until I found that documentation page.

Comment: Your answer is nearly correct, but this folder is called node_module **s**

Comment: OMG. That was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a package.json file on the folder you are trying to install the package, then it will create the node_modules folder correctly.

Basic package.json

```
{
    "name": "application-name",
    "version": "0.0.1"
}
```