# How can my module require a specific version of npm?

Tags: dependencies, npm, node-modules

I am writing an npm module which comes with some scripts, e.g. `npm run cureCancer`.

I want these scripts to accept extra parameters, which is possible only with npm 2 and above, e.g. `npm run cureCancer -- fast`

This means that my module depends on npm 2 or newer, so I added the following to package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "npm": "^2.7.5"
}
```

Then I ran `npm install`.

Then I ran `npm -v`

- expected: `2.7.5`
- observed: `1.4.23`.

And of course `npm run cureCancer -- fast` fails.

How can my module require a specific version of npm?

As a bonus, I would like npm@2 to be installed locally only, so as not to mess with people's global setup.

**UPDATE**

Adding npm to the dependencies works, but it doesn't override the global version when using the `npm` command. To use the locally installed npm instead, use `./node_modules/.bin/npm`. This is pretty ugly and unfriendly, so creating an alias might be a good idea.

Comment: Seems to me like you want users to have a _global_ `npm@2` installation. The [`"engines"` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) can serve as an advisory of such a requirement to your users.

Comment: `npm -v` will display the version of `npm` you have installed _globally_. Installing `npm` _locally_ will not add it to your `PATH`, hence the difference in output.

Comment: All I want is for  `npm run cureCancer -- fast` to work correctly within my module. If I can achieve this without forcing a specific version globally, that would be better. I think a local install should work for this... No? If not, how would I use the locally installed version of npm?